# which .net project reference has SessionFactory.CreateEclSession(subject.Session)

Tags: event-system, ecl, sites-9.1

i am trying to write 1 event system code for ecl items. i am facing error to use following method SessionFactory.CreateEclSession(subject.Session)

following is the compiler error shown in visual studio:
[image]

following are the potential fixes suggested by VS but none suits my purpose:
[image]

any suggestion or guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have following dlls in your project references in order to have ECL session.

```
Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.dll
Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2.dll
```

Comment: Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.dll it has the session factory. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

It is in `Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2` dll.

```
namespace Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2
{
    public static class SessionFactory
    {
        public static IEclSession CreateEclSession(Session tcmSession);
        public static IEclSession CreateEclSession(string username);
    }
}
```